# Spark Installation Problems

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am following instructions from here:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/apache-spark-python#gs.WEktovg

I downloaded and prebuilt version of Spark , untarred it and mv it to /usr/local/spark.

According to this, this is all I should have to do.

Unfortunately, I can run the interactive shell as it cant find the file.

When i run :

```
./bin/pyspark
```

I get

```
-bash: ./bin/pyspark: No such file or directory.
```

I also notice that installing it this way does not add it to the bin directory.

Is this tutorial wrong or am I missing a trick?

Comment: Are you sure you ran `./bin/pyspark` ? Your error says `/.bin/pyspark`

Comment: Error in copying it. I ran ./bin/pyspark. Will update

Comment: You need to change your working directory to /usr/local/spark. Then this command will work. And also, when you untar it, it usually will not add it to bin folder. You need to add it manually by adding the path to environment variables.

Comment: Thank you! update the this as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your working directory to `/usr/local/spark`. Then this command will work.

And also, when you untar it, it usually will not add it to bin folder. You need to add it manually by adding the path to environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Update your working Directory to `/usr/local/spark` and execute the command. Hopefully this will fix the issue.